# Wait for redux-form to finish before using syncErrors

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using `redux-form` to handle form data inside redux.

I have noticed that in order to use the `syncErrors` state, to check for validation errors, I need to first check that the actual `redux-form` has finished rendering, otherwise React will complain that it cannot find `syncErrors` of undefined - implying that `this.props.accountForm`, the `redux-form`, is not yet available.

Is this the expected behavior?

**This is the code that breaks:**

```
render() {
  return (
    <SignUpInForm>
        <div>
          <Field
            name="name"
            component={renderTextField}
            label="Full Name*"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Field
            name="email"
            component={renderTextField}
            label="Email Address*"
          />
        </div>
      <div>
        <Button
          disabled={!!this.props.accountForm.syncErrors}
          onClick={this.signUp}
        >
          Save
        </Button>
      </div>
      ..
    </SignUpInForm>
  )
}
```

**And this is the code that works:**

```
render() {
  return (
    !!this.props.accountForm && (
      <SignUpInForm>
          <div>
            <Field
              name="name"
              component={renderTextField}
              label="Full Name*"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <Field
              name="email"
              component={renderTextField}
              label="Email Address*"
            />
          </div>
        <div>
          <Button
            disabled={!!this.props.accountForm.syncErrors}
            onClick={this.signUp}
          >
            Save
          </Button>
        </div>
        ..
      </SignUpInForm>
    )
  )
}
```

To me, this looks a bit ugly!

Note - this is how I am connecting it to the reducer:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    accountForm: state.form.accountForm
  };
};

Account = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(Account);

export default withRouter(
  reduxForm({
    form: "accountForm",
    validate
  })(Account)
);
```

Then the combineReducers file looks like this:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { reducer as reduxForm } from "redux-form";

export default combineReducers({
  form: reduxForm
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this time I was validating the `redux-form` wrong!

I solved this by using the following `redux-form` props to check for errors:

```
const { invalid, submitting } = this.props;
```

Then in the submit button I do something like this:

```
          <Button
            disabled={invalid || submitting }
            onClick={this.signUp}
          >
```